# how to display files inside directory

Tags: c#, list, directory

i am trying to get list of files inside the directory in this case "c:\dir\" (ofcourse i have files inside) and i wanted to display the name of those files in console program build in c#....

initially i did this....

```
static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dir\");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Read();


        }
    }
```

how can i see the name of those files.......
any help would be appreciated.....

thank you.

(further i would like to know if possible any idea on sending those file path towards dynamic html page.... any general concept how to do that...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "file names" you mean literally just the **names** and *not* the full **paths**:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dir");
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i) {
    string path = filePaths[i];
    Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

Comment: actually may i know if its possible for me to send those path dynamically towards html file.... i mean the path that i see in my console application... C:\dir\a.jpeg........... C:\dir\home.txt etc.

Comment: So if you wanted to display a message "Directory is empty..." or something like that would you use an if/else statement?  If so what would the criteria for if be?  I tried "if i == 0" as my if criteria but it's not working.

Comment: @MattP: Sounds like you want to check `if (filePaths.Length == 0)` (outside the `for` loop)?

Answer (score 4):

Loop through the files and print them one at a time:

```
foreach(string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\dir"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(folder);
}

foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\dir"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Comment: but it doesnot shows me the folder names e.g i got 5 folder and 1 .jpeg it only displays .jpeg.

Comment: Use Directory.GetDirectories to print all the folders as well. I edited the post to show this.

Comment: GetFiles returns an array of type FileInfo , it should be foreach(FileInfo fi in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Dir")) { Console.WriteLine(file.Name);}

Comment: @tike: Then you want `GetFileSystemEntries` instead of `GetFiles`.

Comment: @bnkdev: You're mistaken; `Directory.GetFiles` returns a string[]. The `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` method returns a FileInfo[].

Comment: actually may i know if its possible for me to send those path dynamically towards html file.... i mean the path that i see in my console application... C:\dir\a.jpeg........... C:\dir\home.txt etc.

Comment: Send paths towards an HTML file? I'm not sure what you mean by this. Do you want to fill an HTML file with paths? Are you trying to host a web page that lists files on your local drive?

Comment: actually this is basic web server development process.. i want to learn how to create a dynamic html page which could take path for files.... for example above filepaths.

basically i want to create a html file which could give me link to that particular file which was displayed in my console application.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (string filename in filePaths) {
  Console.WriteLine(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if there are many files in the folder you will have memory problems.
 .Net 4.0 contains a fix: [C# directory.getfiles memory help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970603/c-directory-getfiles-memory-help)

Answer (score 1):

`foreach(FileInfo f in Directory.GetFiles())
Console.Writeline(f.Name)`