# *FASTEST* directory listing

Tags: c#, file-io, directory

I have massive directories, and I would like to read all the files as fast as I can.  I mean, not DirectoryInfo.GetFiles fast, but 'get-clusters-from-disk-low-level' fast.

Of course, .NET 2.0, c#

Similar question was here, but this approach wasn't any good:

[C# Directory listing massive directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941223/c-directory-listing-massive-directory)

Someone suggested pInvoke on FindFirst/FindNext.  Anybody tried that and is able to share results?

Comment: Using reflector it looks like DirectoryInfo.GetFiles ultimately boils down to FindFirstFile/FindNextFile kernel32 calls anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a "normal" approach, basically everything boils down to `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, you don't really get much faster than that... and that isn't super-turbo-fast.

If you **really** need speed, look into reading the [MFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_File_Table) manually - but know that this requires admin privileges, and is prone to break whenever NTFS gets updated (and, oh yeah, won't work for non-NTFS filesystems). You might want to have a look at [this code](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=22695.0) which has [USN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) and MFT stuff.

However, perhaps there's a different solution. If your app is running constantly and needs to pick up changes, you can start off by doing one slow `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` pass, and then use directory change notification support to be informed of updates... that works for limited users, and doesn't depend on filesystem structures.

Answer (score 3):

For the best performance, it is possible to P/Invoke NtQueryDirectoryFile, documented as ZwQueryDirectoryFile.

(That short of accessing the disk directly and reading the raw file system structures directly, which usually is not practical.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like [this DirectoryManager](http://codepaste.net/msm8b1) and refine it by your needs. Works faster than the .NET Framework `GetDirectories()` or `GetFiles()` because we ommitted there cross-platform checkings and adaptations.

Comment: Very nice little class, it uses `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile`. Personally I would add a copy of the code here instead of linking to another site, just in case that one goes down.

Comment: @Eugene Cheverda The DirectoryManager link no longer works :P