# Identifying bad ReparsePoints with GetDirectories() in .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, reparsepoint

I am using `Directory.GetDirectories()` with a Linq statement to loop through all directories in a folder that aren't system folders, however I am discovering a bunch of bad `ReparsePoints` in the folder, which is causing the method to take a long time as it times out on each bad reparse point.

The code I am currently using looks like this:

```
subdirectories = directory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(d => ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
         && ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System));
```

I have also tried using code like this for testing, but it also hangs for a full minute or so on the bad folders:

```
foreach (var item in dir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes);
}
```

It should be noted that the above bit of code works fine in .Net 4.0, but in 3.5 it will hang for a  minute on each bad reparse point.

Trying to open these folders manually in Windows Explorer results in a "Network Path Not Found" error.

Is there another way to loop through good subfolders inside a folder that doesn't use the `Attributes` property, or that bypasses the bad reparse points?

I have already tried using `Directory.Exists()`, and that is equally slow.

Comment: I have found that streaming the input from a process is virtually the same performance-wise and requires no exception handling and is actually more robust and reliable.  Strange but true (at least for me it's true)

Comment: @Rachel, have you tried just excluding `FileAttributes.ReparsePoint` from search with your `Where` clause?

Comment: @Noseratio Yes, accessing the `FileAttributes` property causes the performance problem.

Comment: This may be a silly question - but did you try putting the FileAttributes.ReparsePoint exclusion as the first check in your where clause?  i.e. .Where(d => ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != FileAttributes.Reparsepoint) && ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
         && ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System))

Comment: @SeanHosey Yes, accessing the `FileAttributes` property is what causes the problem since the directory doesn't actually exist, so when it tries to check it to see if it contains `ReparsePoint` or any other value, it takes about a full minute to figure out the `FileAttributes` property of the bad reparse point.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: [*FASTEST* directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582823/fastest-directory-listing/8827241#8827241)

> *For the best performance, it is possible to P/Invoke `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, documented as `ZwQueryDirectoryFile`*

From MSDN: [`FILE_REPARSE_POINT_INFORMATION` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540354(v=vs.85).aspx)

> This information can be queried in either of the following ways:
>
> Call [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing `FileReparsePointInformation` as the value of FileInformationClass and passing a caller-allocated, `FILE_REPARSE_POINT_INFORMATION`-structured buffer as the value of `FileInformation`.
>
> Create an IRP with major function code [`IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and minor function code `IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY`.