# How can I determine if a directory exists on a network drive or not?

Tags: c#, file-io, .net-3.5, directory, reparsepoint

I'm looping through directories on a network drive, but some directories are bad `ReparsePoints` and don't actually exist.

Using `Directory.Exists` returns `true` after about 30 seconds, and so does `new DirectoryInfo(dir).Exists`, however trying to open the folder in windows explorer returns the following error message:

> I:\MyFolder is not accessible.
>
> The network path was not found.

Trying to access the directory contents using `dir.GetDirectories()` throws an exception because the path doesn't exist, and so does other methods such as `dir.GetAccessControl()`.

Is there a way to determine if a network path exists or not when there is a valid `ReparsePoint` for the folder?

The only folder attributes are `Directory, ReparsePoint`

Comment: Doesn't your recent question ask about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750974/identifying-bad-reparsepoints-with-getdirectories-in-net-3-5

Comment: @Shoe It's definitely related, but I wasn't sure if I should edit that one or not since the question in slightly different and an answer was already posted. The goal of the 1st question was to find a different way to determine directory attributes that doesn't encounter the performance hit on bad reparse directories, while this one is to determine if the directory actually exists or not. Currently I am checking attributes on another thread, and assuming its bad if it doesn't return a result within 3 seconds, but assuming its bad isn't working for my current logic