# GetDirectories fails to enumerate subfolders of a folder with #255 name

Tags: .net, file-io, special-characters

My application is C# 3.5 runs on Windows 7 Ultimate, 64 bit. It goes through all folder subfolders to perform its job. However, it fails (falls into the infinite loop until StackOverflow.com exception) if run against the folder which name is only one symbol which is #255.

To reproduce, you can do the following:

1. run Windows Explorer create C:\Temp folder in this folder
2. create new folder and rename it with Alt-255 (using numeric keypad)
3. create subfolders "first" and "second" there
4. create subfolders "1" and "2" under Temp

So you now have:

- C:\1
- C:\2
- C:\ \first
- C:\ \second

For such C:\Temp folder with a subfolder with the name #255 (or more #255 symbols) the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
  public static string[] GetDirectories(string pathToTraverse)
  {
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in new DirectoryInfo(pathToTraverse).GetDirectories())
    {
      result.Add(subFolder.FullName);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
  }

  public static void TraverseFolders(string folderToTraverse)
  {
    foreach (string subFolder in GetDirectories(folderToTraverse))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(subFolder);

      TraverseFolders(subFolder);
    }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    TraverseFolders(@"C:\Temp");
  }
}
```

will never end and will give you result like:

C:\Temp\ 
C:\Temp\1
C:\Temp\2
C:\Temp\ 
C:\Temp\1
C:\Temp\2
C:\Temp\ 
C:\Temp\1
C:\Temp\2
C:\Temp\

So how do I correctly enumerate such folder subfolders?

Comment: Another problem you might face later is some kind of recursive linking. Using hardlinks, symlinks, junctions, reparse-points,...

Comment: I suggest you post your entire code, or a cutdown version that demonstrates the problem and see if anyone else can reproduce it. What you describe does not seem plausible.

Comment: @David, does it give you all subfolders correctly? For me it give me subFolder THE SAME as pathToTraverse.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, yes, but fortunately there is FileAttributes.ReparsePoint attribute available.

Comment: I believe running the code on Windows 7 (and Vista, I think) will make it work.

Comment: @Jhourlad, I am on Win7 64 bit Ultimate - unfortunately, it does not

Comment: Does `ReparsePoint` cover every kind of link that can cause such a problem? There are not just reparse points.

Comment: I believe so - at least ignoring reparse points works fine for me so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following program runs perfectly and does not result in a stack overflow error.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToTraverse = @"C:\Desktop";
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in new DirectoryInfo(pathToTraverse).GetDirectories())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(subFolder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
chaff
Python
__history
 
ÿ
```

The penultimate apparently blank line is in fact the directory named Alt+255.

Consequently I believe that your problem is not related to the code you have shown and is in fact elsewhere in some code that you have not presented to us.

I'm running on Windows 7 with VS 2010 Express targeting .net 3.5.

---

Now that your update shows all your code, I can see what is happening. The .net code is presumably trimming the directories and so the folders with white space get lost.

So `@"C:\Temp\ "` is trimmed to `@"C:\Temp\"`.

I found the following trivial modification avoided the infinite loop:

```
TraverseFolders(subFolder+@"\");
```

Adding a trailing path separator stops the trimming that appears to occur in the call to DirectoryInfo. In the example above this means that `@"C:\Temp\ \"` is passed to DirectoryInfo which yields the expected results.

I guess you should probably use a routine that only adds a trailing path separator if one is not already present. And you may want to avoid hardcoding the @"\" as path separator, but that's for you to work out now that you know what the underlying cause of your problem is.

Comment: Please see my code and updated explanations above. The #255 folder itself is well-shown, but trying to enumerate its contents leads to infinite loop.

Comment: Try running the program on Vista and Windows 7. I think they have already fixed some issues with ASCII and ANSI standards.

Comment: @Alex I've worked out what your problem is and included it in an update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, David, this works. Well, I can always use Path.DirectorySeparatorChar to avoid hardcoding \.

Comment: And BTW this is very strange to me that .NET supposes #255 to be the blank symbol - looks like a bug.

Comment: @Alex I think it will use a trim function that strips whitespace and I guess ALT+255 will be regarded as such

Comment: `Directory.GetDirectories()` still looks like a bug: it returns (without trailing slash) nonexistent subfolder with the same name for directory named by ALT+255: `"C:\ \ "`

Answer (score 1):

ASCII character 255 is not fully  supported by Windows. For visual sake it translates the this character into a "_" character.

**The reason?** 
ASCII 255 character displays as an invisible character but takes up one character space, therefore, a confusion between this character and the ASCII 32 SPACE character. This character only works on Windows 98 and lower versions including all DOS versions (if I'm not mistaken).

**EDIT:** Windows 7 now has some fix with some extended characters. The code should be handled fine if running on that OS.

**The solution?** 
Don't use this character as file and folder name because your program.

or

1. Let the program check for extended characters and skip them if they exists before it loops indefinitely.
2. Allow the program to folders with extended characters but if in case it loops continuously, place a code that will skip that folder and move to the next folder item.
3. Your code should work with Vista and Windows 7, make that your program requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however unfortunately I cannot prevent a user of my program to avoid this character. I am seeking a way to enumerate such folder contents. For example, Windows Explorer itselft, FAR and other tools perfectly shows the contents of such folder so why .NET Framework doesn't?

Comment: This seems a little odd and not what I observe. Are you running Windows 98 or some non-Unicode version of Windows. I don't see any "_" in my Windows 7 installation.

Comment: Vista and Windows 7 already fixed this and some other issues with extended characters and now handles them literally so, in theory, the code should work on those systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - seems that David's solution with simply adding slash works.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth do you have a folder called "_" anyway? It is not descriptive at all.. the idea of a folder is that you can contain all related files in that folder and possibly use subfolders to group them even more; folder names should generally be descriptive - for example many sites have a folder called "css" or "stylesheets".. Doubt I need to explain what they're for tho as they're pretty self-explanatory.. I, personally, cannot think of a *single* situation where I would be using 1 symbol for a folder name. It is best, in my opinion, to stick to alphanumeric characters and seldom use symbols (it is safer as you never hit these situations on any operating system).

Comment: I am sorry but this is not an answer to my question. I do not need recommendations of how to use file system. I am writing a software which is intended to enumerate ALL folders at a user drive even if they are looking the ways to hid their information with the tricks like special symbols in names.

Comment: And application crashing just because it doesn't like a folder name is unacceptable. It's not for the application to decide how the user may name his folders.

Comment: Ah ok well if you'd explained that bit in the original question then I wouldn't have posted that. I therefore do not think down-voting my answer is fair as there was information I did not know. For all I know it could've been a website in which case you would have control over the folder names. Please up-vote my post again...

Comment: OK will do when the system allows this (cannot vote the same answer again)

Comment: Just remembered I had to edit it before you could do that - should be fine now. Didn't mean any offense by the way - just to me how to name folders is obvious and I wrongly assumed that it was for an app in which you have control over the folders.