# How to open a file with a name consisting of spaces?

Tags: .net, file-io, whitespace

The question is similar to another my question ( [GetDirectories fails to enumerate subfolders of a folder with #255 name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368054/getdirectories-fails-to-enumerate-subfolders-of-a-folder-with-255-name) ).

In my C# 3.5 .NET application I am trying to open a file using

```
using (FileStream fileStream = 
new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

However, if a file name is like "   ", the code fails with the exception

> *A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional
>   information: Could not find a part of
>   the path "C:\Temp\   ".*

Is it possible to open such file with .NET means or not?

P.S. This is not artificial situation (like someone suspected for my previous question), such file can be perfectly created by popular software, e.g. Thunderbird can create such file if you create a mail folder with a name consisting of spaces only.

To reproduce, do the following steps:

- Download and install Far Commander or Mozilla Thunderbird
- In Far create a file with a name " ". In Thunderbird, create a subfolder in your mail account with a name " "
- Try to open a file named " " using the code above

Comment: I can't create such folder in win xp? How did you do that?

Comment: This is not me, this is Thunderbird.

Comment: Or you can use any file commander like Far or Total Commander which can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the typical .Net way of accessing files won't account for the special character. My initial answer was assuming that the file name was a space, but I see now that you intended for it to be the Alt+255 character. Here's a sample Console app that uses the Win32 API to open the file:

```
class Program
{
    public const UInt32 GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000;
    public const UInt32 GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    public const UInt32 GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    public const UInt32 GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000;
    public const UInt32 FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
    public const UInt32 FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
    public const UInt32 CREATE_ALWAYS = 2;
    public const UInt32 CREATE_NEW = 1;
    public const UInt32 OPEN_ALWAYS = 4;
    public const UInt32 OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    public const UInt32 TRUNCATE_EXISTING = 5;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, System.UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, System.UInt32 dwShareMode, IntPtr pSecurityAttributes, System.UInt32 dwCreationDisposition, System.UInt32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle oSafeHandle = CreateFile(@"Path to your folder\ ", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        using (FileStream oFS = new FileStream(oSafeHandle, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("file was opened");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob! Looks like a solution - I will test and let you know.

Comment: Your solution works - thanks. The only thing that I'd like to mention that the file is not of 255 symbols, it really contains only spaces in name. However, it still work with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Windows requires you to specify a filename, you can't create a file with a name of just a single space. [Windows Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You'll need to first create a file with a valid name, then reference that in your code.

Comment: Thanks but this comment is one that can be sent this to Mozilla. I have nothing to do with creation of such files. I only need to open already existing files.

Comment: Added to repro steps of how such file can be created to the question description.