# copy all the files form folder to another folder without permission limit

Tags: c#, .net

Please help me I am stuck!

I want to copy all the subfolders from specified path to another folder. I have succeeded to to it on normal folders but sometimes I get an unauthorizedaccessexception and all the program crashes.
I want to be able to continue running the program and just skip the unauthorizedaccess folders...

is there any way to do it??

thank you

this is my code:

```
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(strSourcePath, "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(strSourcePath, strTargetPath));
}

//Copy all the files
Foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(strSourcePath, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
     File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(strSourcePath, strTargetPath));
 }
```

the crash happens when I try to execute this line: `Directory.GetDirectories(strSourcePath, "*",
                                                                            SearchOption.AllDirectories`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerating Files Throwing Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756626/enumerating-files-throwing-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the exception and move on.

ex pseudocode:

```
for file in folder {
    try {
        operation
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ){
    continue; //Probably should log here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in way to enumerate files recursively that doesn't die when it gets an exception in some directory. So you need to implement recursion yourself.

If the enumerations throws the error, you can look at this question:

[Enumerating Files Throwing Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756626/enumerating-files-throwing-exception/7756679#7756679)

If it's the copying that throws the error I'd just add a `try catch` clause for those exceptions and then move on with the next file.

Comment: its not the copying its the GetDirectory method

Comment: @user1018192 in that case you can simply use my answer from the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to include both parts of directory and file creation in try-catch error handle. And in case of error, just log the error or show a message, but it will continue the search and copy.

You can also look at [Recursively resume directory scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068182/recursively-resume-directory-scan)

Errors occurs in denied access directories or failed permissions on file, but no worries, it goes well. Don't forget to check if you are setting the correct permissions from the original side.