# Recursively resume directory scan

Tags: c#

I have all this directory's created:

```
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0101
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0102
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0102\dir010201
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir02
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir02\dir0201
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03\apalqoei
dirdemojob3: C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03\xpt01
```

The program recursively searches for directories and works well.

If the scan encounters an error, for example, in "dir02\dir0201", it stops the scan. I would like to start the scan in another run of the program, or next day, but don't start from the dir01. I want to resume in "dir02\dir0201" and continue like a normal scan.

If you start again from "dir02\dir0201", ain't gonna scan dir03 and so on. I'm looking for this ability to resume directory scans.

Thank you.

---

```
    public static void DirSearch(string _job, string _sDir, int _side)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string _d in Directory.GetDirectories(_sDir))
            {
               // here save to txt or anything else
                DirSearch(_job, _d, _side);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
              // show error
        }
```

This is important part of the code: recursion. This get's all directories and ignores those common errors of access denied, etc.

Nor GetDirectories nor EnumerateDirectories (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383573.aspx) have the ability to do what I want. So I'm trying to see if somebody had the same problem: getdirectories() and be able to resume if vpn drops or in another day.

edit: thank you ChrisF for the edit.

Anyway, this code is usefull but there is no direct solution for my problem. I'm coding a function to do what I need, and later will post it here.

// ************************************************

UPDATE: I don't know how to add this other way, so here goes.

This next code reads the directories and saves it to a sql server and writes some info on the console. It is a recursive function but it controls the level in a special way.
This way can be used to do do file scan for backup or re-sync and resume the job, if it fails in anyway. 
I found that it is no possible to resume directory search. But you can always get the full list and then backup the files based on the saved list. This way, you can always resume the job.

```
public static void DirSearchByLevel(string _job, string _sDir, int _side)
{
    //
    // verify that root dir exists
    // code here
    if (!Directory.Exists(_sDir)) { KONSOLE("Directory does not exists: " + _sDir); return; }
    //
    // save root dir - complete 0 (not yet); dirlevel = 0 (root of search directory)
    KONSOLE("Scanning " + _sDir + " - complete=" + _complete.ToString() + " level=" + _dirlevel.ToString());
    errodb = tools.SaveDirToDB(_job, _side, _sDir,
                                      DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue,
                                      _complete, _dirlevel);
    //
    // save base dir - complete 0 (not yet); dirlevel = 1 (base of search directory)
    // *****************************************************************************
    try
    {
        foreach (string _d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            //KONSOLE(_d);
            errodb = tools.SaveDirToDB(_job, _side, _d,
                                       DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue,
                                       _complete, _dirlevel);
            // get dirlevel +1 to scan next level; recursion will downlevel it next
            _dirlevel += 1;
            DirSearchByLevel(_job, _d, _side);
        }
        // if none directory was found, we still at 0; otherwise, go back one level
        if (0 != _dirlevel) _dirlevel -= 1;
        // *****************************************************************************
        //
        // save base dir; complete = 1;
        _complete = 1;
        errodb = tools.UpdateDir(_job, _side, _sDir, _complete, _dirlevel);
        KONSOLE("Update " + _sDir + " - complete=" + _complete.ToString() + " level=" + _dirlevel.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        KONSOLE("Error in " + _sDir + " - complete=" + _complete.ToString() + " level=" + _dirlevel.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is a demo result of this function:

```
Scanning C:\temp\dirdemo - complete=0 level=0 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01 - complete=0 level=1 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0101 - complete=0 level=2 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0101 - complete=1 level=1 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0102 - complete=1 level=2 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0102\dir010201 - complete=1 level=3 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0102\dir010201 - complete=1 level=2 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01\dir0102 - complete=1 level=1 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir01 - complete=1 level=0 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir02 - complete=1 level=1 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir02\dir0201 - complete=1 level=2 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir02\dir0201 - complete=1 level=1 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir02 - complete=1 level=0 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03 - complete=1 level=1 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03\apalqoei - complete=1 level=2 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03\apalqoei - complete=1 level=1 Scanning
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03\xpt01 - complete=1 level=2 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03\xpt01 - complete=1 level=1 Update
C:\temp\dirdemo\dir03 - complete=1 level=0 Update C:\temp\dirdemo -
complete=1 level=0
```

That's all. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of your code?

Comment: Save the last directory you scanned somewhere, and at next scan skip dirs till you get there.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and many ways you might need it to be done.. You just need to save information related to your scan somewhere.  If directories aren't deleted or moved regularly, just always save the last directory scanned somewhere. If they are moved or whatever, you may need to save more.

Comment: I can post my code yes, but it works very well. Going to post it on another reply.

Comment: Thank you all. Guess I just have to always do a full scan.

Answer (score 2):

- Designate a particular file to be a temp file used by this program.
- When the program starts, don't scan any files that are listed in that temp directory.
- When you finish scanning a directory add it to the end of the file.
- When you finish scanning *all* of the directories (or whatever condition indicates that they should be scanned again when the program is run next time), wipe the file (so that they can be scanned again the next day).

Another option that is the same general idea, just slightly modified, is to do this:

- Designate a particular file to be a temp file used by this program.
- When the program starts, if the temp file is empty, populate it with all of the directories that need to be processed
- Go through each path in the file and process it
- When you process a directory, remove it from the file

Comment: The real situation is to scan all directories of a remote NAS but the VPN sometimes dies. So I have to start it all over again... half an hour to get the whole list. This is not practical.

Comment: Ops, continue my last, command. So I want to find a way to continue in the point I was at. And I just do this once a day, at night.

Comment: @user2275929 I fail to see how the approach I suggested wouldn't work well in that context.  It sounds like you're doing just what I expected of it.  I added  a modified option, if you think it would be better.

Comment: Thank you all. Guess I just have to always do a full scan.

Comment: public static void DirSearch(string _job, string _sDir, int _side)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string _d in Directory.GetDirectories(_sDir))
            {
               // here save to txt or anything else
                DirSearch(_job, _d, _side);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
              // show error
        }

Comment: @user2275929 So I guess you didn't bother to read my answer at all.  If you aren't interested in solving your problem, I guess that's up to you.

Comment: not at all. I read it carefully and I thank you for your time. You said one thing that I will do and later will put the code in here. It is the part that "Go through each path in the file and process it". I'm gonna make a function that will do more or less that approach.