# How to delete oldest folder created from local disk using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I created a service which will move backup to a disk on daily basis.

But before moving the backup i need to check the available space of the disk.
If available space is less than 1 TB need to delete the oldest backup folder from the disk and then continue the backup

I got the available space using below code

```
DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo(@"H:");
long FreeSpace = (((driveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace) / 1024) / 1024 / 1024) / 1024;
```

Now i need to check `FreeSpace` value is less than 1

```
if(FreeSpace < 1)
{

  //need to delete the folder in the path H:\backup\
  //whose created date is the oldest
}
```

eg:-

```
 > If available space is less than 1 TB and H:\backup\ contain 3 folder
    > 19062017   -- created on 19/06/2017 
      20062017   -- created on 20/06/2017 
      21062017   -- created on 21/06/2017

    > We need to delete the folder 19062017 with its content
```

How to achive the same in C#

Comment: Why the down vote ??

Comment: I think using the folder name which is a date is best method :              DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("folder").GetDirectories().AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Name)).LastOrDefault();
             info.Delete();

Comment: Half of your post is unrelated to your question. The calculation for free space has nothing to do with finding the folder to delete. Your question is really "How do I enumerate and sort folders by name?" Of which you'd find plenty of examples if you'd search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can delete by following way.

```
FileSystemInfo fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo("H://backup").GetFileSystemInfos().OrderByDescending(fi => fi.CreationTime).First();
Directory.Delete(fileInfo.FullName,true);
```

Comment: Thanks it working fine. Only change is 'OrderByDescending' not needed that will delete the latest folder. Need to delete the oldest one. So 'OrderBy'

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
var infoDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"H:\backup");
var directory = di.EnumerateDirectories() 
                    .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTime)
                    .First();
```

Now you will have the DirectoryInfo object of the first folder in `directory`, You can proceed with delete option as like this:

```
foreach(System.IO.FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles()) file.Delete();
foreach(System.IO.DirectoryInfo subDirectory in directory.GetDirectories()) subDirectory.Delete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

The FileSystemInfo class. Here's a line of code to file the oldest in a directory:

```
FileSystemInfo fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath).GetFileSystemInfos()
.OrderByDescending(fi => fi.CreationTime).First();
```

You'll have to make this recursive somehow. [There's also a thread on how to get all files in a disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332703/c-sharp-how-to-list-all-files-and-folders-on-a-hard-drive)

Comment: upvoting for the effort