# C# display all files from selected folder

Tags: c#, wpf, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I want to display all the files from a selected folder.. ie files from that folder and files from the subfolders which are in that selected folder.

example -

I have selected D:\Eg. Now I have some txt and pdf files in that. Also I have subfolders in that which also contain some pdf files. Now I want to display all those files in a data grid.

My code is

```
public void  selectfolders(string filename)
{      
     FileInfo_Class fclass;
     dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filename);

     FileInfo[] info = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
     foreach (FileInfo f in info)
     {

        fclass = new FileInfo_Class();
        fclass.Name = f.Name;
        fclass.length = Convert.ToUInt32(f.Length);
        fclass.DirectoryName = f.DirectoryName;
        fclass.FullName = f.FullName;
        fclass.Extension = f.Extension;

        obcinfo.Add(fclass);  
     }
     dataGrid1.DataContext = obcinfo;
}
```

What to do now?

Comment: You might also find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should [recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) select files from all subfolders.

```
public void  selectfolders(string filename)
{
    FileInfo_Class fclass;
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filename);

    FileInfo[] info = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
    foreach (FileInfo f in info)
    {
        fclass = new FileInfo_Class();
        fclass.Name = f.Name;
        fclass.length = Convert.ToUInt32(f.Length);
        fclass.DirectoryName = f.DirectoryName;
        fclass.FullName = f.FullName;
        fclass.Extension = f.Extension;
        obcinfo.Add(fclass);
    }
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
    foreach(DirectoryInfo directory in subDirectories)
    {
        selectfolders(directory.FullName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Just use

```
FileInfo[] info = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

which will handle the recursion for you.