# How to extract zip file which exist on ftp server using C#

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am using [ftplib](http://ftplib.codeplex.com/) for uploading files on ftp server using following code

```
FtpConnection ftp = new FtpConnection(serverip, ftpuser, ftppassword);
ftp.Open();
ftp.Login();
ftp.SetCurrentDirectory("domain/wwwroot");

    void CreateDirOnFtp(string sDir, FtpConnection ftp)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(f);
                        ftp.PutFile(f, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath));
                    }

                    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                    {
                        string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;

                        if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(dirname))
                        {
                            ftp.CreateDirectory(dirname);
                        }

                        ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(dirname);
                        CreateDirOnFtp(d, ftp);
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                }

            }
```

But this code is not iterating through all directories so missing some directories and files on ftp server.

so i decided to upload zip file on ftp and extract it on ftp server but
I cant find any way to extract file which exist on ftp server.

How can i do this?
Or any other better way to upload multiple directories and file on ftp server

Answer (score 0):

You cant tell sever to extract file using FTP protocol. To do that, you would need to create some web-service that will extract it after upload, or some scheduled task that will extract all the zips it find.

And if you would create a web service, then FTP uploading can be ditched altogether. Service method can accept zipped content and extract it on the server side.

Comment: i dont want to use webservice?

Comment: any other way or third party library?

Answer (score 0):

Try [recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c) go through your directory and upload it via ftp. I think this is much simpler than unzip a file on the server without a webservice.