# Counter inside a recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, counter, delete-file

I need to count the number of files deleted in this recursive function.  Since it's recursive I cannot use `if` statements, and C# does not support global variables.  Any alternatives?

```
static void DirSearch(string path)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if (filename.Equals("desktop.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                    //count++
                }
                Console.WriteLine(filePath); // print files
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dirPath); // print directories
            DirSearch(dirPath);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: of course C# supports global variables. where did you get the idea it does not?! also, ever thought of passing in an extra parameter to keep hold of the number of files deleted? add an extra param to your method for the counter.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Technically it doesn't they're all members of some type or another.

Comment: As an aside, I would rename the function.  A search implies that it will traverse a data source and return information about it, but the function is deleting all desktop.txt files.  It would probably also be worth adding a parameter for filename rather than hard-coding it to desktop.txt.

Comment: @DanLyons: agreed! this code was just to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to pass in something for it to count into. I'd do this using `ref`, for example:

```
static void DirSearch(string path, ref int count)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if (filename.Equals("desktop.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                    count++
                }
                Console.WriteLine(filePath); // print files
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dirPath); // print directories
            DirSearch(dirPath,ref count);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
int count = 0;

DirSearch(@"C:\SomePath",ref count);
```

Then you can use `count` as normal as you had commented out in your code.

Comment: need to pass `ref count` as an argument to the recursive call to DirSearch

Comment: Why `ref` when you can return the number of directories affected?

Comment: +1. Returning number of processed files would be much cleaner than `ref`.

Comment: You're right you could also do a return like @wdosanjos answer, entirely down to what you prefer, I've upvoted his answer as well.

Answer (score 8):

Try a recursive `count` as follows.  So `DirSearch` returns the `count` of deleted files.

```
static int DirSearch(string path)
{
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if (filename.Equals("desktop.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);

                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(filePath); // print files
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dirPath); // print directories
            count += DirSearch(dirPath);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a ref variable (so you don't need to pass something that is correctly initialized):

```
static int DirSearch(string path)
{
    try
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if (filename.Equals("desktop.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(filePath); // print files
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dirPath); // print directories
            count += DirSearch(dirPath);
        }
        return count;
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did You also consider a non-recursive solution like presented here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/929418/2979680