# Recursion that traverses tree to count children of a Node not working as expected

Tags: c#, recursion

Pretty basic problem, I have a method that loops through all the children of a node in a tree and counts them. Problem is, the counter doesn't seem to be working properly, maybe due to some scoping issues.

```
public static void CountChildNodes(Node node, int counter)
{
    foreach (Node child in node.Children)
    {
        counter++;
        CountChildNodes(child, counter);
    }
}
```

The counter resets after each iteration of the recursion, and in the end it just resets to the `int` I started with. I'd like the counter to simply end with the number of children the initial Node had. Is there a simple solution, or is there something wrong with the way I'm approaching this problem?

Comment: Try `ref int counter` like [this recursion example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19913489/3504007)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because the `counter` parameter is being passed by value. That means that when you pass it as a parameter, the values gets copied into an entirely new variable. Any changes you make to that variable won't affect the variable that you initially passed.

For example, in this code:

```
int i = 5;
AddFiveToInt(i);
Console.WriteLine(i);

// Prints: 5
```

There are two ways to approach this. Either have your `int` be passed by reference:

```
public static void CountChildNodes(Node node, ref int counter)
{
    foreach (Node child in node.Children)
    {
        counter++;
        CountChildNodes(child, ref counter);
    }
}
```

Or return the latest value:

```
public static int CountChildNodes(Node node)
{
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (Node child in node.Children)
    {
        counter++;
        counter += CountChildNodes(child);
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and great explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That was becauase `counter` is passed by value. Pass by `ref` instead.

```
public static void CountChildNodes(Node node, ref int counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
public static int CountChildNodes(Node node)
{
        int c = 0;
        if ((node.Children == null) || (node.Children.Count == 0))
            return c;

        foreach (Node child in node.Children)
        {
            c++;
            c+=CountChildNodes(child);
        }
        return c;
}
```