# C# - Find a file within all possible folders, and open that file

Tags: c#, file-io

I want my application to search through the whole computer for a specific file, and open it.
I tried:

```
var files = new List<string>();
foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady == true))
{
    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d.RootDirectory.FullName, "Kalimba.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
```

Got error: No access C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18.

Comment: So what's your problem? What did u try so far?

Comment: I want a pony! But it ain't gonna happen!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Upvoted for the correction to bring in-line with SO rules =) I get flamed so much even though i try!

Comment: you could probably ignore the recycle bin

Comment: I'd use the windows search API http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7388

Comment: Your application needs to be launched with **administrator rights**

Comment: @Jonesy - Can i do something like: if name contains "1212", "2414", "4324" something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Well your `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` method throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception cause you don't have access to this hidden directory.

Correction: **catch the exception**.

---

UPDATE: as the comments say, you're getting all your files in a single `GetFiles` call, so catching the exception won't help. Slightly modify your code to manually get the list of directories, so you can catch and handle the exception for the specific directory you have not rights on.

See [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c) for a complete example.

Comment: Just catching the exception won't do. The operation would stop. The directory should be skipped.

Comment: Catching the exception is not a solution since OP uses `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. Then it's likely that he won't find his file. He needs to use his own method to traverse all folders recursively to catch an exception at one folder or file instead of at the root-folder.

Comment: I read the question too fast, you're both totally right. Edited the question. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.