# What need I do to get this code to work in a Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, portable-class-library, compact-framework2.0

I'm wondering if the Portable Class Library is even more restricted in functionality than the Compact Framework.

I'm trying to port a CF/Windows CE app (runs on a handheld device) to a Xamarin solution that will target Android, iOS, Windows Phone, and perhaps other things.

One of the problems I run into, though, is that this legacy code (which works under CF):

```
public static List<string> GetXMLFiles(string fileType, string startingDir)
{
    const string EXTENSION = ".XML";
    string dirName = startingDir;
    // call it like so: GetXMLFiles("ABC", "\\");  <= I think the double-whack is what I need for Windows CE device...am I right?
    var fileNames = new List<String>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dirName))
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(f);
            if (extension != null)
            {
                string ext = extension.ToUpper();
                string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
                if (fileNameOnly != null &&
                    ((ext.Equals(EXTENSION, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) &&
                     (fileNameOnly.Contains(fileType))))
                {
                    fileNames.Add(f);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dirName))
        {
            fileNames.AddRange(GetXMLFiles(fileType, d));
                // from Brad Rem's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186198/why-is-this-function-returning-nothing-although-there-is-a-match/22186351?noredirect=1#22186351
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```

...won't compile in the Xamarin/CPL solution. I get, "The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context" and right-clicking that word does not afford a "resolve" option.

Is there a way to get PCL to recognize "Directory" or must I completely rewrite the code? If the latter, does anybody have any suggestions on what to do/use in its stead?

Relatedly, is there an URL that will show me what is [not] available in PCL and/or a site that will show how much of a provided block of code is "PCL-ready"?

### UPDATE

The first image in [this article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/) is very illuminating. Later on, it specifically talks about "Directory" not being available in the PCL scenario.

### UPDATE 2

I downloaded the PCLStorage package referenced by Daniel Plaisted below to allow me to access the file system within a PCL project.

Using the sample code at the start of the download page [http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/] as a starting point, I've gotten this far:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetXMLFiles(string fileType, string startingDir)
{
    const string EXTENSION = ".XML";

    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync(startingDir, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); //CreateFolderAsync(startingDir, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    List<string> fileNames = await folder.GetFilesAsync(EXTENSION);
    return fileNames;
}
```

...but "EXTENSION" as the arg to GetFilesAsync() is not right. I get with this, "*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'*"

So what need I do to get all the *.XML files the folder?

### UPDATE 3

This compiles, but I'm not at all sure it's the right way to do it, besides the fact that it simply gets *all* the files from the folder, rather than just those that match "*.XML":

```
public async Task<List<IFile>> GetXMLFiles(string fileType, string startingDir)
{
    const string EXTENSION = ".XML";

    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync(startingDir, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    IList<PCLStorage.IFile> fileNames = await folder.GetFilesAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

    return fileNames.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows Phone applications do not use the file system of the operating
>   system and are restricted to using isolated storage to persist and
>   access files, so this namespace does not provide any additional
>   functionality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I reckon then, the same is true for Android and iOS so that each would need its own "take" on how to search for files?

Comment: iOS allows you to access the file system within your app's sandbox.  Android is similar, but also allows you to write to external SD cards.

Answer (score 2):

Since in a PCL I was unable to get a StreamWriter from a string (it required a stream), I created a simple interface to get some of the data from the platform implementation. You can also do this with DirectoryInfo and FileInfo.

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Text/IStreamLocator.cs

The implementation is really simple as well, only needs one single compiler flag for WP8:

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/WP8/SimplyMobile.Text.Platform/StreamLocator.cs

Recursively search for *.XML files:

```
    private static void PrintDirectory(IStreamLocator locator, string dir)
    {
        foreach (var file in locator.GetFileNames(dir, "*.XML"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file);
        }

        foreach (var di in locator.GetFolderNames(dir, "*"))
        {
            PrintDirectory(locator, di);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has a scanner which will give you a rough idea of the portability of your code: http://scan.xamarin.com/

For some guidance on how to deal with non-portable APIs from PCLs, see my blog post: [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx)

For file IO in particular, you can try my [PCL Storage](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon As for how to get just the .XML files, you will need to filter the list yourself, since PCL Storage doesn't provide APIs to get files matching a wildcard or extension.  Also, the code you have in your update 3 won't recursively search for files like your original code did.  If you need more help getting the code working I'd suggest posting another question specific to PCL Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Shim](https://github.com/cureos/shim) if all your platforms are supported by it.

API coverage for file operations isn't exhaustive, but it gets you a long way. As a bonus, it also gives you access to a bunch of other stuff.