# Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]

Tags: c#

I have been trouble with an cast error for the following method in a PCL which I have no issues with in a legacy class library.

```
    protected FolderInfo GetFolderInfo(string folderPath, int level = 0)
    {
        FolderInfo folderInfo = new FolderInfo(folderPath);

        if (settings.MaxDepthLevel == 0 || level < settings.MaxDepthLevel)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo currentDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

                foreach (DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in currentDirectoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    if (settings.SkipHiddenFolders && directoryInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    FolderInfo subFolderInfo = GetFolderInfo(directoryInfo.FullName, level + 1);
                    folderInfo.Folders.Add(subFolderInfo);
                    subFolderInfo.Parent = folderInfo;
                }

                foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in currentDirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    if (settings.SkipHiddenFiles && fileInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    folderInfo.Files.Add(fileInfo);
                }

                folderInfo.Files.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
            }
        }

        return folderInfo;
    }
```

I get the following error:
[image: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll - Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]' to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'.]

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'.

In a PCL, how differently could I write this above 'working' code to behave differently?

Thanks and best regards
Michael

Comment: Bigger question is why System.IO.FileSystem.dll is being used.  You do have to document the target you tested.  It definitely looks broken in CoreFx right now, a rather plain casting bug.  File a bug with the project.

Comment: Thanks I submitted a problem through VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Phone applications do not use the file system of the operating
>   system and are restricted to using isolated storage to persist and
>   access files, so this namespace does not provide any additional
>   functionality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

You should also take a look at this [SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615794/what-need-i-do-to-get-this-code-to-work-in-a-portable-class-library)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I cannot use PCLStorage either:
PCLStorage 1.0.2 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86).
Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.165 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86).
Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86).
Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86).