# How to get all files/folders in a folder in Portable Class Library (PCL)

Tags: loops, printer-control-language, getfiles

I have searched everywhere for a code sample but for the life of me I cannot find a working solution to get all files/folders in a particular folder in an Indexer library I am coding as a Portable Class Library.

I was linked to [What need I do to get this code to work in a Portable Class Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615794/what-need-i-do-to-get-this-code-to-work-in-a-portable-class-library) after I had a cast error question at [Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313780/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-io-filesysteminfo-to-type-system-colle) however PCLStorage is limited to LocalStorage which is the app folder.

```
    private async Task<List<IFolder>> GetDirectoriesAsync(string startingDir)
    {
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync(startingDir, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        IList<IFolder> folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

        return folders.ToList();
    }
```

I wanted for the user to be able to pick any folder i.e. C:\ or external drive or anywhere that the user can browse.

Thanks in advance.

My full code is at:
[IndexerLib](https://github.com/McoreD/TreeGUI/blob/d7b2f18769a5a58925302deac3603972fb7b7f4c/treegui4/ShareX.IndexerLib/Indexer.cs)