# Get informations about files in folder

Tags: c#, file, directory, streamreader, filereader

Please can you help me how can i get informations about files in folder? Because i need exactly get trace from all files in folder.

**For Examples:**

**Trace is:**

```
G:/Program Files/test/vse - here is all image files what i need
```

I created list where i will save trace from this files. And i need automatically get trace from individual files in the folder.

Important is that all files have individual name "1 - 100.jpg" if all will be work correctly so this will be out informations:

**I need this result:**

```
List<string> trace = new List<string>() which contains all trace with his name about file.
```

**For Example:**

```
G:/Program Files/test/vse/1.jpg
G:/Program Files/test/vse/2.jpg
G:/Program Files/test/vse/3.jpg
...
...
G:/Program Files/test/vse/100.jpg
```

I really thx for all answers.

Comment: Can you show the code you have written so far to solve that problem? Also, please review your tags: Why do you think a `StreamReader` or a `FileReader` is required to solve your problem?

Comment: Have you checked out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Explain "trace" and "automatically get trace to individual files in the folder".

Comment: O. R. Mapper - problem is that i havent any code for this functions because i dont know how do it. Because i dont know how can i get all trace from individual files in folder add to list.
CodeCaster - I edited it.

Comment: Do you mean a "file path" by a "trace"? It looks like it based on your example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var listOfFiles = new  List<String>();
        string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                lisOfFiles.Add(fileName);
            }
```

for more info look here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I will try it and write feedback from it

Comment: Code for copy-and-pasting may solve the current problem of the OP, but does not necessarily help them understand how to solve similar problems, and less so will future visitors with similar, yet not the same problem benefit from this answer. Note that links can go dead, so it would be helpful to add an explanation of what you are doing right in the answer as well.

Comment: @mapper or soemthing, See i added the link. you should see this link is from msdn they dont usually go dead. i did not claim this code is mine!!!

Comment: I'd say the code is self explanatory enough that it doesn't need much explanation.

Comment: He also added a little typo to get a bit of a challenge to the C&P'ing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the static methods [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory.GetFiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that return an array of string containing the path of your files.

Additionally, you can use the extension method **ToList()** to convert the collection to a **List<string>**.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileInfo provide a lot of information about files, so you could convert it to Fileinfo:

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(directoryPath)).Select(x => new FileInfo(x));
```

The FileInfo has Name attribute that return the File name also has an Extension property which return the file extensions and so on.