# How do I list all of the sub directories in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a directory with 30 sub directory files in it `"C:\School\Grad School (Comp Sci)\Thesis\Apps"`. How do I list all of the sub directories in `SrcML.Net`?

```
[TestCase]
public void CalculateSimpleProjectStats()
{
    var dataProject = new DataProject<CompleteWorkingSet>("Android Apps",
        Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\School\Grad School (Comp Sci)\Thesis\Apps\accelerometer-app-master"),
        "..//..//..//SrcML");
    Debug.WriteLine("Parsing android-pedometer-studio....");

    dataProject.UpdateAsync().Wait();

    NamespaceDefinition globalNamespace;
    Assert.That(dataProject.WorkingSet.TryObtainReadLock(5000, out globalNamespace));

    DisplaySensorTypes(globalNamespace);
    //DisplayWhetherAppIsUnitTested();           
    DisplayCallsToOnSensorChanged(globalNamespace);            
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the above code? Do you get an error? If not, what are your results? You can edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3e2f6e5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method of the `DirectoryInfo` class:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("..//..//..//SrcML");
var subDirectories = di.GetDirectories();
```

The method will be *called* from the current directory, so it will *automatically* find the correct path.

If you want to retrieve **all** subdirectories (subdirectory of subdirectory and so on) from the `SrcML` directory, than have a look at the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c) that @aquinas posted in his comment to you question.