# Creating a consuming foreach in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to create a consuming `foreach` loop in C#?
basically loop through a Collection items and simultaneously consume them?

In plain English: Instead of just looping through the elements, remove the item from the collection, do stuff with it, then go to the next.

**EDIT** I neglected to mention that I am using a producing consuming pattern and this is why I wanted a consuming foreach. Most of the answers here are completely valid for the simple case I described before this edit, although what I wanted is described in my answer

Comment: Use a [`Stack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the item"?  Do you mean you want to reduce the number of items in the collection?

Comment: You can look into the producer-consumer pattern, .NET provides the `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: You can't modify a collection while you iterate through itlike that,  you'll get a runtime error.

Comment: @roryap
Yes but in a foreach loop

Comment: You can not do that with an `IEnumerable` as it only exposes a way to iterate the collection.  Unless the underlying class just happened to be implemented in such a way, but you wouldn't know that if you are consuming just `IEnuemerable`.

Comment: @RonBeyer has it right.  You can't do that in a foreach loop.  You can use a for loop

Comment: I would recommand that you have a look on RX and TPL DataFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the answer from StepUp the collection used in the `foreach` loop is immutable. But a similar thing could be performed with `BlockingCollection` and using `GetConsumingEnumerable` which consumes the Collection items while iterating through them. Given that my collection is part of concurrent produce consume scheme (that I neglected to mention in my question) this suits me more. In simpler cases though the other answers, using a stack or queue are much more appropriate, or simple loop that would loop from the end of the collection, down to the start and remove the item on the way (a start to end loop with removal will skip items or end up in an `IndexOutOfBounds Exception`

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`Stack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx)(last-in-first-out) or [`Queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx)(first-in, first-out).

A nice example is [this "recursive" queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929418/284240) which lists all the files in a directory.

Comment: Although your answer seems nice, I would prefer the blocking collection as stated in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The collection used in `foreach` is immutable. This is made by design.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) says:

**The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.**

**Update 0.0:**
It is possible to use `for` loop to edit collection:
  To add an item to collection, you can use `for` loop:

```
List<string> coll = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
for (int i = coll.Count-1; i>=0 ; i--)
{ 
   /* You can assign value to an item:
    coll[i] = "";       
   You can add an item to the collection:
   coll.Add(i.ToString());*/
   coll.RemoveAt(i);
   //or coll.Remove("your string value to delete");
}
```

Comment: So show a way that it *can* be done, i.e. using a for loop.  As it stands, this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: You cannot remove from a list in a `for` loop that increments up because each time you remove something the `Count` will go down.  You either need to start at the end and decrement or use a `while` loop like Konamiman's answer

Comment: Downvoted because using an incremental loop will either end up to `IndexOutOfBounds` Exception or lead to items being skipped

Comment: @StepUp removed the downvote and upvoted as it is valid for the simple case that I described in the question, although information was missing from my question

Comment: @StepUp You need to loop until `i >= 0` or you'll miss the first one at index 0.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments for your question, using a Stack or a Queue is the best option for a "process-then-remove" pattern. If for some reason you dont't want to use these specialized classes, you can do something like the following with a plain `List`:

```
var items = new List<Item>() {item1, item2, item3};
while(items.Count > 0)
{
    ProcessItem(item[0]);
    items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

But what you cannot do is to modify the collection inside the `foreach` loop, as explained in StepUp's answer.

Comment: Although your answer seems nice, I would prefer the blocking collection as stated in my answer

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Of course. I just wanted to show a poor man's approach to point out that it is not such a complex problem.

Comment: Yes. But i did not state my question fully as this had to with concurrency and i had locks there. This helps as i can remove the locks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a "consuming foreach" but probably what you are looking for is the TPL DataFlow.

See for example:https://leanpub.com/tpldataflowbyexample/read or [MSDN: Create a DataFlow Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh228604(v=vs.110).aspx) or [MSDN: Implement a Producer / Consumer Scenario](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx)

A very very  basic example can look like this:

```
  var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(n => Console.WriteLine(n));

             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 actionBlock.Post(i);
             }

             Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

You can also link multiple blocks to  create a more complex consuming strategy with forks and so on. You can also defined varying Scheduler types to the steps.

For very easy scenarios this might be oversized, but TPL is a very good scaling solution with give you a lot of control on how the dataflow should look like.