# Check for files and creating folders and moving files in C#

Tags: c#

I have no problems when I want to create a new folder
I'm working with

Directory.CreateDirectory

Now I'm trying to get all image files from my desktop and I want to move all images to that folder which was created with  Directory.CreateDirectory

I've testet file.MoveTo
from here

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt");
```

to here

```
file.MoveTo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\test.txt");
```

This works perfect.
Now I want to do that with all the image files from my dekstop

```
(Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Images");)
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

Comment: Directory.GetFiles ok but I want to move all images from my desktop to a new created folder on my desktop

Comment: So? Determine which files exist that match your criteria (e.g. certain file extension) and move them. What's stopping you?

Comment: Yes this is extacly what I want to do Timon Post but how could I do that?

Comment: This is easy... You can find this on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:
You can filter files in a specific directory and then looop through search results to move each file, you might be able to modify search pattern to match on a number of different image file formats

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("PathToDirectory", "*.jpg");
    foreach (var fileFound in files)
    {
        //Move your files one by one here
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileFound);
        file.MoveTo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\" + file.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is extatcly what I need.

Comment: But I've tryed it with  var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop", "*.jpg");
            foreach (var fileFound in files)
            {
                //Move your files one by one here
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileFound);
                file.MoveTo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Images");
            } and I get an error

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? Could you paste it in the comments?

Comment: System.IO.IOException

Comment: have you replaced User with your windows username in the path?

Comment: my windows username is user :D

Comment: Can you paste in more details of that exception (as much of the description as you can)? Unfortunarelly what you have provided so far is not enough to get to the bottom of what's causing it

Comment: This message I've translated it from german to englisch {"Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist.\r\n"}
A file could not be created when the file is available

Comment: Please see my edited answer, as it turns out, file.MoveTo needs a path including the name of the file that is being moved 'file.MoveTo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\" + file.Name'

Comment: THANK YOU. You are my hero !! I love you man #nohomo  it worked perfect !

Comment: Yeah! I'm so happy now !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Example code of getting images with certain extentions from one root folder:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        // path to desktop
        var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        //get file extentions by speciging the needed extentions
        var images = GetFilesByExtensions(new DirectoryInfo(desktopPath) ,".png", ".jpg", ".gif");

        // loop thrue the found images and it will copy it to a folder (make sure the folder exists otherwise filenot found exception) 
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            // if you want to move it to another directory without creating a copy use:
            image.MoveTo(desktopPath + "\\folder\\" + image.Name);

            // if you want to move a copy of the image use this
            File.Copy(desktopPath + "\\"+ image.Name, desktopPath + "\\folder\\" + image.Name, true);
        }
      }

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesByExtensions(DirectoryInfo dir, params string[] extensions)
    {
        if (extensions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("extensions");

        var files = dir.EnumerateFiles();
        return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you man! I this is what I mean ... I get no error but my folder is still empty why?

Comment: Oh sorry I did not work with string searchPattern = "*.bmp" + "*.jpg";

Comment: I've tried it again with  string searchPattern = "*.bmp" + "*.jpg";
            foreach (string img in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), searchPattern))
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(img);
                file.MoveTo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Images");
            } and my folder is still empty i dont know why

Comment: I'm on it wait a second

Comment: Thanks but why    File.Copy(desktopPath + "//" + image.Name, desktopPath + "//folderr//" + image.Name, true); and not move? I don't understand the part with +//folder// I'm getting errors

Comment: File.Copy creates a copy of the image and move's that copy to the (desktop  path + foldername + name_of_destination file) you can use File.Move but this is just another approach

Comment: I've updated the question now you can choose to move the copy or just the image itself without