# is File-List from a Folder (very simple)

Tags: 2sxc

Has anyone used this file-list from a folder? so called 'very simple'? we are looking for something to be used as a file storage/file repository module but this seems very complicated to set up for just a simple repository module.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the folder would be any folder in your portal, not an ADAM folder.

In this case, you just need to write some standard C# using System.IO

Something like explained here: [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)